# What were the allegorical significances of the scenes of a bird and butterfly coming out of Barbara Kean's mouth, if any?

Tags: analysis, gotham

In *Gotham* s2 e8, named [*Rise of the Villains: Tonight’s the Night*](http://gotham.wikia.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Villains:_Tonight%E2%80%99s_the_Night), Barbara was shown in Gotham Cathedral about to marry Jim Gordon. But things turned nasty as "the priest became the Penguin, Theo Galavan the wedding's pianist, and the guests Arkham Asylum prisoners." Just after that *a bird popped out and flew away out of her mouth.*

In *Gotham* s2 e11, named [*Rise of the Villains: Worse Than A Crime*](http://gotham.wikia.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Villains:_Worse_Than_A_Crime), Gordon was having bad dreams about Barbara Kean dangling from the church rooftop. *A butterfly fluttered out of her mouth* as Gordon released her in the dream<sup>[1](http://www.ew.com/recap/gotham-season-2-episode-11)</sup>.

---

So, two episodes; same character; more or less same scene.

Were there any allegorical meanings behind these scenes?

What did they want to mean by a bird and butterfly coming out of Barbara's mouth?

Are there any significance of these scenes or am I being just too pedantic?

Is there any logic behind the depictions of the more or less same scenes in the show?

Comment: I did wanted to ask it but forgot